# How can I add a text link to the create page of an event that will take the user to the create page for another object?

Tags: page-layout

I'm new to Salesforce, and I am trying to add some functionality to the create event page that is basically a link the will take the user the the create page for a custom object.

Ideally this would be done from within the Layout Editor.

eg a link with the text `This is a special event...` is displayed to the user when they are viewing the create event page. If the user clicks the link, then they are taken to the create page for the custom object.

Is this possible? It seems simple enough, but I can't find any info on how to achieve this. Maybe I'm using incorrect terminology in my searches?

Answer (score 2):

As you cannot display a formula field in edit mode, you would have to create a Visualforce page to override the default Event pagelayout, and display the link to the page you want your users to visit. Best resources to get you up to speed is the Visualforce Developer Guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm

After you created the VF page, you override the standard New event button and associate it with the newly created VF page. Basic steps:

1. From the custmize activities settings go to Event Buttons and Links.
2. Click Edit next to the New Event button.
3. Pick Override with Visualforce page and select the name of the Visualforce page you want to run when users click the button.
4. Optionally, enter any comments to note the reason for this change.
5. Click Save.

Don't forget to read the considerations for overriding standard buttons: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_override_considerations.htm&language=en_US